# What does initWithObjects:&value mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html) they init NSSet object with &value I have never see this before. Can someone explain this for me? From document its seem `initWithObjects:` required C Array of Object, how come &value become Array? From my understanding & use to reference address like the one I saw in &error.

```
- (void)removeEmployeesObject:(Employee *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
          withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
          usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveEmployees] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
          withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
          usingObjects:changedObjects];
}
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#_arrays

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a good, clear question for someone that doesn't understand how the address of a single object works out to be equivalent to a C array with that one object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C an array is basically a pointer to an address. Here `&value` is a pointer that points to an address where `(Employee *)value` is saved. You can think this as a single value array. If there are more than one element, the other elements will be saved one next to each other after the first element. But the pointer always points to the first element. And that is why the function needs a `count` argument to know exactly how many values to extract from the first pointer.

Comment: Thanks, about to ask how does one differentiate if it is a single value or array. That `count` explain my other doubt.